# problem with how we define tuples as the funtion input in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

This ia an assignment problem:

> In class, we have shown you a program which mimics transactions done
> on a bank account. For this we have ﬁrst deﬁned a data-type for
> transactions:
>
> type transaction = Withdraw of int | Deposit of int |
> CheckBalance | ChangePassword of string | Close
>
> We have added two new
> transactions to the example done in class. In class, we deﬁned a
> function make-account which generates a bank account when given an
> opening balance. In this exercise, you are asked to modify this code
> and generate a password-protected bank account. Any transaction on the
> bank account should only be possible, if one provides the right
> password. For this, implement the function makeProtectedAccount with
> the arguments and types shown below. let
> makeProtectedAccount(openingBalance: int, password: string) = This
> function takes in the opening balance as a ﬁrst argument and the
> password as a second, and will return a function which when given the
> correct password and a transaction will perform the transaction. One
> crucial diﬀerence to be noted right away is that in the new code I
> want you to print the balance on the screen instead of returning it as
> a value.

I tried to declare a function in OCaml which takes as input a tuple. But it gave me an error when I tried to tell the compiler what type are each of the elements in the tuple. However, the compiler compiles when I put parenthesis around the type definition of each of the items in the tuples. Furthermore, I tried to put multiple statements as the execution sequence of a matched case in a match statement, but the compiler cannot recognize it. How can we execute multiple statements for a matched case?

function declaration with Compilor error:

`makeProtectedAccount(openingBalance: int, password: string) =`

function declaration without compilor error:

```
makeProtectedAccount((openingBalance: int), (password: string)) =
```

Codes that I wrote so far, as you can see the compiler dosen't understand that |Deposit  is a matched case as it does not indent the statement automatically:

```
let makeProtectedAccount ( (openingBalance : int) , (password : string) ) =
      let balance = ref openingBalance in
      let pass = ref password in
      fun (( passs : string ), (tras : transaction)) ->
        if !passs = pass then
          match trans with
          | Withdraw q -> (if balance >= q then balance := !balance - q ; Printf.printf "withdrawing %d dollar, you have %d dollar left" q !balance
        else Printf.printf "Invalid: withdrawing more money than you have!")
    |Deposit q -> balance := !balance + q; Printf.printf "Deposit %d, you have now %d ", q !balance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple questions here

#### How to write a function that accepts a tuple

Like you did, or

```ml
let makeProtectedAccount ((openingBalance, password): int*string) =
```

#### How to write multiple statements in a `match` case

Also as you did

```ml
match trans with 
| Withdraw q -> Printf.printf "statement 1\n"; Printf.printf "statement 2\n" 
| Deposit q  -> Printf.printf "statement 3\n"; Printf.printf "statement 4\n"
```

I think a problem is the stray `,` in your last `printf`. Also, `passs` is not a `ref`, no need to dereference it with `!`. Also, **parenthesize the statements** in the `then` branch

This should work for example

```ml
let makeProtectedAccount ((openingBalance:int), (password:string)) =
      let balance = ref openingBalance in
      let pass = ref password in
      function 
      | p, Withdraw q when p = !pass -> 
           if !balance >= q then (balance := !balance - q; Printf.printf "withdrawing %d dollar, you have %d dollar left" q !balance) 
           else Printf.printf "Invalid: withdrawing more money than you have!"
      | p, Deposit q when p = !pass -> balance := !balance + q; Printf.printf "Deposit %d, you have now %d " q !balance 
      | _, _ -> ()
```

---

By the way, if there is no particular reason to accept a tuple, it would be more idiomatic to write a `function` with two parameters

```ml
let makeProtectedAccount (openingBalance:int) (password:string) =
```